# How to remap double shift keystroke to caps lock key?

Tags: remapping, capslock

I'm using vim, so I've remapped <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. But sometimes I still need caps lock to type long upper case characters. So I'm wondering whether it's possible to remap quick double <kbd>Shift</kbd> keystrokes to caps lock?

Please kindly consider Windows and Mac OS X platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for Windows
environments.

This will toggle <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed twice within 500 milliseconds

```
Shift::
if (A_ThisHotkey == A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey <= 500)
{
    SetCapsLockState % !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
}
return
```